# React/Javascript display API data shows hard coded links instead of hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So I'm messing around with this API and for the description it has the links hard coded like `<a href="/">Bunch of words</a>`, so it just shows exactly that on my browser. How would I display the description to look normal in my app?

Here is the API https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin

and this is just a simple way I got the description to display

```
const Tokens = ({coin}) => {
 return (
      <p>{coin.description.en}</p>
  )
 }
```

This would end up showing all the a tags on the browser instead of converting them into a clickable link

```
  <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/peercoin\">Peercoin</a>, <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/primecoin\">Primecoin</a>, and so on.\r\n\r\nThe cryptocurrency then took off with the innovation of the turing-complete smart contract by <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum\">Ethereum</a> which led to the development of other amazing projects such as <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/eos\">EOS</a>, <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/tron\">Tron</a>, and even crypto-collectibles such as <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/buzz/ethereum-still-king-dapps-cryptokitties-need-1-billion-on-eos\">CryptoKitties</a>.",
```

Is there a way to display the description so that it looks like a normal paragraph with hyperlinks instead of literally showing the hard coded  tags?

Also, if I only wanted to show like the first two sentences, how would I cut out the rest of the paragraph?

Comment: Does [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) do what you need? Keep in mind that you should only use this if you fully trust the source of the HTML and you may wish to do some form of sanitizing of the source HTML to be sure. As for getting the first two paragraphs, I guess you could do some pattern matching using Regex to match a paragraph and take the first to matches or use `.split('\r\n\r\n')` and take the first two indexes.

Comment: what is the /r and /n called? I don't know what those do so I'd need to research which ones make sense for what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: `\r` is a CR (Carriage Return) and `\n\ is a LF (Line Feed). They are used in the API you mentioned to split the text one `\r\n` is used to move a single line and it appears it uses `\r\n\r\n` to move two lines for paragraphs.

Comment: Here is a really quick example of roughly what you want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pdjrlu

Answer (score 0):

Like Jacob said, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop by utilizing interpolated string literals.

```
const apiResponse = `<a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/peercoin\">Peercoin</a>, <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/primecoin\">Primecoin</a>, and so on.\r\n\r\nThe cryptocurrency then took off with the innovation of the turing-complete smart contract by <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum\">Ethereum</a> which led to the development of other amazing projects such as <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/eos\">EOS</a>, <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/tron\">Tron</a>, and even crypto-collectibles such as <a href=\"https://www.coingecko.com/buzz/ethereum-still-king-dapps-cryptokitties-need-1-billion-on-eos\">CryptoKitties</a>."`
...
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: apiResponse}}></p>.
```

However, `\r` and `\n` won't be understood by the HTML. You can replace these whitespace characters with unicode escape sequences that HTML will understand like so:

```
const cleanedAPIResponse = apiResponse.replace("\n", "<br\>").replace("\r", "\u000D");
...
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: cleanedAPIResponse}}></p>.
```

Note: Not too sure about these replacements. FYI, `\r` is known as a 'carriage return'.

If you wanted only the first two sentences, an idea could be to search for the second instance of '.' in the API response. Then you can truncate the rest of the string literal, and append the appropriate closing tags based on the appearance of the tags going from left to right and which do not have matching closing tags in the string already.

Comment: why would I need to manually write out the description from the API in my code though? what if the description is like 1000s of lines and only the end piece has those hard coded a tags

Comment: @designxd10 You wouldn't. I just did that because permission errors in my environment barred fetch requests from resolving, so I worked directly with the data. You had the correct code for fetching from the API so I didn't change anything from it, instead I just coded the parts you were asking for (displaying the HTML string). I would look at Jacob Smit's most recent comment under your post - the linked repo has pretty much what you are looking for. Although if you were only looking for the first two sentences, I think you'd have to do something with splitting the API response around '.'

Comment: Splitting on sentences would be a bit more complex, there are alot of edge cases (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop#Ending_sentences for uses of '.') that could mean you are splitting too early in a sentence.

Comment: Yes, you're right in the general sense, and I just realized that the API response contains anchor tags with hrefs containing URLs. However, the OP seems to be looking at cryptocurrency descriptions, in which you wouldn't really find those cases listed in the Wikipedia article. Also, successive sentences will be separated with a space and a '.' (assuming grammatical punctuation is correct), so the OP could split on '. ', and thus find where the two sentence mark is.

Comment: So, the OP could do something like first split based on the paragraph delimiter '\r\n\r\n', then split based on a sentence delimiter like '. ', and pick the first two indices (if the paragraph contains at least two sentences).

Comment: Makes sense, splitting on strings that are outside of my control always makes me cautious. I probably would have just handled this with a `text-overflow: ellipsis` and possibly included a more/less option.